# how to get sum of anonymous field in dynamic linq query

Tags: asp.net, linq, dynamic

to show sum of field in footer row of gridview i want to get sum from my dynamic list, InTopSuppliersView() is in separate assembly DAL while gridview is inside presentation layer.

Code in DAL:

```
public static dynamic InTopSuppliersView()
{

    var _pd = from pd in InTopSuppliers()
                join pm in PdnmasterDALC.InTopSuppliers() on pd.Pdnmasterid equals pm.Pdnmasterid
                select new
                {
                    RefNo = pm.PDNRefNo,
                    Date = pm.Date
                    Quantity = pd.QuantityApprovedUOM,
                    Rate = pd.Rate,
                    Amount = pd.Amount
                };

    return _pd;
}
```

Code on form:

```
var tmp = InTopSuppliersView();
gvPDNDetail.DataSource = tmp;
gvPDNDetail.DataBind();

gvPDNDetail.FooterRow.Cells[3].Text = tmp.SUM(o => o.Quantity).ToString();
```

i want to get sum of fields Quantity and Amount created dynamically in query

[image]

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: What is `e.Row.Cells[3].Text` since there is no variable `e` in `InTopSuppliersView`.

Comment: sorry i updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Let's see if I understood you correctly:*

---

You return a `dynamic` from `InTopSuppliersView` because you want to return a list with anonymous type, right? And then you want to call `.Sum` on that list, but it won't work with the syntax because dynamic doesn't know what a lambda expression is (`o => o.Quantity`):

> Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

So I'm guessing you want to do something like this:

```
gvPDNDetail.FooterRow.Cells[3].Text = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)tmp).Sum(o => o.Quantity).ToString();
```

---

Or just change the return type to `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<dynamic> InTopSuppliersView()
{
    return from pd in InTopSuppliers()
           join pm in PdnmasterDALC.InTopSuppliers() on pd.Pdnmasterid equals pm.Pdnmasterid
           select new
           {
               RefNo = pm.PDNRefNo,
               Date = pm.Date
               Quantity = pd.QuantityApprovedUOM,
               Rate = pd.Rate,
               Amount = pd.Amount
           };
}
```

Then call it like before:

```
// Observe the casing on Sum
gvPDNDetail.FooterRow.Cells[3].Text = tmp.Sum(o => o.Quantity).ToString();
```

---

**EDIT:**

From your comments I think I know what's happening. You have the `InTopSuppliersView` method in one assembly and the form where you use it in another. I believe the anonymous type created is by default `internal` and thus cannot be used in another assembly. I think it will work if you use `ExpandoObject` instead:

```
public static IEnumerable<dynamic> InTopSuppliersView()
{
    var _pd = from pd in InTopSuppliers()
              join pm in PdnmasterDALC.InTopSuppliers() on pd.Pdnmasterid equals pm.Pdnmasterid
              select new { pd, pm };

    return _pd.Select(o =>
    {
        dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();

        obj.RefNo = o.pm.PDNRefNo;
        obj.Date = o.pm.Date;
        obj.Quantity = o.pd.QuantityApprovedUOM;
        obj.Rate = o.pd.Rate;
        obj.Amount = o.pd.Amount;

        return obj;
    });
}
```

You could also (instead of above) use `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("YourAssemblyName")]` in the project where this method is and change *"YourAssemblyName"* with the assembly name of the forms project.

Comment: i changed the return type of method like this:
public static IEnumerable<dynamic> InTopSuppliersView()
im getting error message('object' does not contain a definition for 'Quantity')

Comment: @IrfanUllah I have updated the answer; remove `var _pd` and return the linq directly or cast on return by changing the return, from `return _pd;` to `return (IEnumerable<dynamic>)_pd;`.

Comment: im getting same error message, when i press => o. (dot) it does not shows fields (properties)

Comment: @IrfanUllah `o` is of type `dynamic` in your code. Properties and methods on `dynamic` won't show in Intellisense, they will be evaluated in runtime. Make sure you have the exact same spelling and casing on the property in the query and in the lambda. Are you getting the error while compiling or in runtime?

Comment: im getting error in runtime, im sure there is spell mistake, one more thing did you consider that first i get return into object (as above in my code), i tried both var tmp = InTopSuppliersView(); and IEnumerable<dynamic> tmp  = InTopSuppliersView(); both do not work.

Comment: @IrfanUllah What strikes me is that you get *'object'* and not something like *'<>f__AnonymousType0<...>'* in the error message. From the code you posted, you should get an IEnumerable of the anonymous type.

Comment: no im not getting such error, i got below through debugging, may be this could help {System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManyIterator<<>f__AnonymousType27<ERPLayers.Model.PdndetailInfo,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ERPLayers.Model.BudgetdetailInfo>>,ERPLayers.Model.BudgetdetailInfo,<>f__AnonymousType28<int,int,int,string,int,int,ERPLayers.Model.SuppliermasterInfo,ERPLayers.Model.BrandInfo,float,string,float,decimal,decimal,float,string,float,string,string,string,ERPLayers.Model.BudgetdetailInfo,string>>}

Comment: @IrfanUllah Sorry, that doesn't help much, it seems like the error is from something else than the code above(?).

Comment: i did debugging again and again, exceptions is thrown at this line "gvPDNDetail.FooterRow.Cells[3].Text = tmp.Sum(o => o.Quantity).ToString();" rest of code is working fine. i checked tmp.Count(); method it also works.

Comment: @IrfanUllah and what type is `o` when debugging? If you set a breakpoint in `Sum(o => o.Quantity)` (by setting the cursor on .Quantity and pressing F9) and hover over `o`.

Comment: i posted value of o at above in my first question, please note that in my real application name of Quantity is QuantityApproved, also try to do sum of other fields in query but failed. im working with .net framework 4

Comment: @IrfanUllah It's hard to find what's wrong with what you have given. Have you tried to make it work with *only* the code that you first posted? We only get bits and parts from you, that makes it hard helping out.

Comment: im sorry for my poor feedback, if you guide i would try to be able inform excly, in fact both methods are 100% same. i posted one who have less fields in it, to not confuse the reader. i tried it on both.

Comment: @IrfanUllah Well, I can try. I'm still wondering what the *type* of `o` is (not what it contains).

Comment: when i mouse over it says "dynamic o" in code, while debugging execution stops at this point, and i mouse over then it shows what i pasted above in the post, that is o {PDNMasterID = 12 .... }

Comment: @IrfanUllah Can you take a screenshoot of the exception when you get the exception and share?

Comment: @IrfanUllah ok, so here you are using another method - ApprovalViewJoinedBudget - (that we never seen) and the question is how that method looks like and what it returns?

Comment: as i explained, that i simplify my code to make it easy to understand, its 100% same inside, im uploading its inside code also, plz see at bottom of question

Comment: using ExpandoObject(); error message (The data source for GridView with id 'GridView1' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content.) what could be reason? while editing assembly solved the problem [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("YourAssemblyName")], but still tmp.Sum(o => o.Quantity).ToString() have error, can't convert float to Int

Comment: @IrfanUllah Well, it's good that something helped, anyway =) Regarding the float to int, maybe you need to do an explicit conversion: `Sum(o => (int)o.Quantity)`.

Comment: thanks a lot @Mario for your kind help. yes i did it trough conversion but it rounds the figure. is there some method to do sum for float types?

Comment: @IrfanUllah So, try this `((float)tmp.Sum(o => (float)o.Quantity)).ToString();`